# Parsing Arabic text in a local html file

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data from a local html file using python with BeautifulSoup, the file has some Arabic text data like titles. My problem is that when i try to print out this Arabic text, i get a strange string. An example of code with its output is provided along with the head section of the file[image], can anybody help me ?[image]

Comment: Could you provide the HTML file you're trying to parse? It might have something to do with the encoding you've set in the <head> section.

Comment: @Mulletfingers999 i edited the question and added a screenshot for the head section.

Comment: I was hoping for it to be in text format so that I could copy the Arabic text you're using. I can't seem to reproduce this error with some generic arabic text I found online.

Comment: دليل الصناعات المصرية - الموقع الرسمى / إجيبجشن أندسترى – الدليل الصناعي الأول في مصر

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with `utf-8` encoding

> open("body.htm", encoding="utf-8")

or target the file to use `utf-8`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```